# How do I get to the StackExchange.com profile page for a user who has only a few accounts?

Tags: support, profile-page

On the individual site profile pages under the Accounts section (for those with many) there is a link:

[image]

This link takes one to the corresponding main StackExchange.com profile page.
However, for users with only a few (linked) accounts there is no link and I can't figure out how to get to that main profile page.

Frustratingly if I try to look up a user on StackExchange.com it gives me Leagues, and the links there take one to the individual site profile pages rather than the main one.

I figure I must be blind and there must be a link somewhere in plain view but I can't find it.  Help!

Comment: Top right of the user profile page?

Comment: @George Yup, just as blind as I feared.  (Thanks.)

Comment: nice gold, by the way

Comment: @Jan Yes, but not mine; that's the profile page of my friend belisarius.  I'm working on [some of my own](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/121/mr-wizard?tab=badges&sort=class) however.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just click on the header: in your example, that would be the "24 accounts" text

[image: pointer at the header]

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  Unrelated FYI: you should have kept the image in PNG or GIF format; your JPG is 31K and degraded; mine is only 7K and crisp.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: There, a non-degraded version with fatter freehand-drawn circle and arrow. Better now?

Comment: @Martijn I can't believe you bothered with that, but yes.

Comment: @Martijn Wait... why does *my* arrow look different in that?  In fact the text color is off too.  How was this new image made?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: dragged your image into Skitch, defaced^Wdrew freehand on it, ran it through http://tinypng.org/ to compress it back down to 35k, and uploaded it here.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: There, *recreated* the image with just my freehand scribbles. :-P My Mac fonts look better than your fonts, btw.

Answer (score 4):

There's a link on their profile page right in the top-right of the screen. 'Network Profile'

> [image]

Comment: That freehand circle looks suspiciously perfect...

Comment: That's two tool generated semi circles joined together perfectly by freehand. I weep at this oval thing of crimson beauty.

Comment: @CodyGray: I only answered this question because I like playing with Awesomescreenshot chrome plugin. At least I got the color right for the circle.

Comment: I'm sorry I cannot Accept your answer too.  I had to pick one and I went with first posted.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard That's OK, the other answer gives you the specific way to get to the equivalent 'view more' option as you requested, whereas my answer takes you to the full Stack Exchange user profile so it's slightly different.